# Groovy GDSL in IntelliJ shows warning `'delegatesTo' cannot be applied to '(com.intellij.psi.PsiClass)'`

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

[image: IntelliJ screenshot with the code below]

When following the guide at https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/docs/IDE-Support.md, I added the following GDSL file to my project

```
def jobPath = /.*\/jobs\/.*\.groovy/

def ctx = context(pathRegexp: jobPath)
contributor(ctx, {
    delegatesTo(findClass('javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory'))
})
```

IntelliJ is underlining the `delegatesTo` call in yellow, with a warning message

> ```
> 'delegatesTo' cannot be applied to '(com.intellij.psi.PsiClass)'
> ```

How do I resolve the yellow underline?

Answer (score 0):

This warning is harmless and can be ignored. The GDSL is correct and will work.

If you still want to resolve the yellow underline, you need to add the relevant IntelliJ classes (i.e. `com.intellij.psi.PsiElement` and `com.intellij.psi.PsiClass`) into classpath of your project, so that the IDE sees the type when analyzing the file.

### Hero's journey

If you follow the guide https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/tools-gradle-intellij-plugin.html#usage to enable IntelliJ plugin support for your Gradle project

```
plugins {
     id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "1.15.0"
}

intellij {
    version.set("2022.1.1")
    plugins.set(listOf("com.intellij.java"))
}
```

then you will end-up downloading 500MB+ of artifacts,

```
Download https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/idea/ideaIC/2022.1.1/ideaIC-2022.1.1.zip, took 2 m 10 s 803 ms (670.22 MB)
Download https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/idea/ideaIC/2022.1.1/ideaIC-2022.1.1-sources.jar, took 14 s 453 ms (179.92 MB)
```

and when unzipped and put on classpath (the gradle intellij plugin does that for you), they contain the `com.intellij.psi.PsiClass` that makes the IDE happy.

This is way too much data to download for one yellow underline, so, instead, having investigated https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/, I noticed that the same file can be downloaded from https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/java/java-impl/232.8660.185/java-impl-232.8660.185.jar.

This suggests to me to add project dependency on just that single jar file

```
repositories {
    maven("https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.jetbrains.intellij.java:java-impl:232.8660.185")
}
```

It's not any better than before though, because that artifact pulls in lots of transitive dependencies of its own.

### Final solution

But, it turns out the Psi classes are in two of those dependencies, so it is enough to add

```
repositories {
    maven("https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases")
}


dependencies {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76821539/groovy-gdsl-in-intellij-shows-warning-delegatesto-cannot-be-applied-to-com
    compileOnly("com.jetbrains.intellij.platform:core:232.8660.185") { isTransitive = false }
    compileOnly("com.jetbrains.intellij.java:java-psi:232.8660.185") { isTransitive = false }
}
```